# Como puedo obtener en un formulario los datos que creé de forma dinamica en otro formulario

Tags: c#

este fue el codigo para crearlos.

```
Modeladodelnegocio.Indicador[] listado = db.MostrarCriterio();
            for (int i = 0; i < listado.Length; i++)
            {

                if (listado[i].getSelect() == "False")
                {
                    Nombre = listado[i].getNombre().ToString();
                    Label myText = new Label();
                    myText.Location = new Point(40, y);
                    myText.Text = Nombre;
                    myText.Size = new Size(120, 20);

                    this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(myText);

                    TextBox mybox = new TextBox();
                    mybox.Location = new Point(300, y);
                    mybox.Size = new Size(150, 200);
                    valores = listado[i].getValores().ToString();
                    mybox.Text = valores;
                    this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(mybox);
                    y += 50;


                }
                else
                {
                    Nombre = listado[i].getNombre().ToString();
                    Label myText1 = new Label();
                    myText1.Location = new Point(40, y);
                    myText1.Text = Nombre;
                    myText1.Size = new Size(120, 55);
                    this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(myText1);

                    ComboBox micombobox = new ComboBox();
                    micombobox.Location = new Point(300, y);
                    micombobox.Size = new Size(150, 200);
                    valores = listado[i].getValores().ToString();

                    String[] cadena = valores.Split(',');

                    micombobox.DataSource = cadena;
                    this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(micombobox);

                    y += 50;


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

y por qué no usas mejor propiedades?

puedes crear unas propiedades asi:

```
public class pUtilidades
{
  // Un atributo privado
  private string saludo = "";

  // Oculto mediante una "propiedad"
  public int saludo 
  {
    get
    {
      return saludo;
    }

    set
    {
      saludo = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Luego desde el otro formulario solo tienes que llamarlas asi:

```
pUtilidades ejemplo = new pUtilidades();

//asi le asignas valores
pUtilidades.saludo= "Hola mundo!";

//asi lo puedes leer/mostrar
Console.WriteLine(pUtilidades.saludo);
```

de esta manera podras llenar tus propiedades con valores desde un formulario y podras acceder a estas desde cualquier otro formulario.